# Issue : Convert an Object to json in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsmutabledictionary

I have one main entity class with name "Store" like :

Store.h :-

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "SignIn.h"

@interface Store : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *storeId;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *storeProfileId;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *storeName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *storeRegion;

@property (nonatomic, retain) SignIn *signIn;

@end
```

Store.m :-

```
#import "Store.h"

@implementation Store

@synthesize storeId, storeProfileId, storeName, storeRegion, signIn;

- (id) initWithCoder: (NSCoder *)coder
{
    self = [[Store alloc] init];
    if (self != nil)
    {
        self.storeId = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"storeId"];
        self.storeProfileId = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"storeProfileId"];
        self.storeName = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"storeName"];
        self.storeRegion = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"storeRegion"];

        self.signIn = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"signIn"];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)encodeWithCoder: (NSCoder *)coder
{
    [coder encodeObject:storeId forKey:@"storeId"];
    [coder encodeObject:storeProfileId forKey:@"storeProfileId"];
    [coder encodeObject:storeName forKey:@"storeName"];
    [coder encodeObject:storeRegion forKey:@"storeRegion"];

    [coder encodeObject:signIn forKey:@"signIn"];
}

@end
```

Here in Store class, i am taking one more class name "Sign In", that include some other attributes.

SignIn.h :-

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface SignIn : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *inTime;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *outTime;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *isStatus;

@end
```

SignIn.m :-

```
#import "SignIn.h"

@implementation SignIn
@synthesize inTime, outTime, isStatus;

- (id) initWithCoder: (NSCoder *)coder
{
    self = [[SignIn alloc] init];
    if (self != nil)
    {
        self.inTime = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"inTime"];
        self.outTime = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"outTime"];
        self.isStatus = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"isStatus"];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)encodeWithCoder: (NSCoder *)coder
{
    [coder encodeObject:inTime forKey:@"inTime"];
    [coder encodeObject:outTime forKey:@"outTime"];
    [coder encodeObject:isStatus forKey:@"isStatus"];
}

@end
```

Now i need to post this Store object on server. So I am creating dictionary using below code :

```
  NSMutableArray *storeJSONArray=[NSMutableArray array];
    for (Store *store in array1) {

        NSMutableDictionary *storeJSON=[NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

        [storeJSON setValue:store.storeId forKey:@"storeId"];
        [storeJSON setValue:store.storeProfileId forKey:@"storeProfileId"];
        [storeJSON setValue:store.storeName forKey:@"storeName"];
        [storeJSON setValue:store.storeRegion forKey:@"storeRegion"];


        //Sign In
        [storeJSON setValue:store.signIn.inTime forKey:@"inTime"];
        [storeJSON setValue:store.signIn.outTime forKey:@"outTime"];
        [storeJSON setValue:store.signIn.isStatus forKey:@"isStatus"];

        [storeJSONArray addObject:storeJSON];
    }

    NSMutableDictionary *dictionnary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [dictionnary setObject:storeJSONArray forKey:@"StoreRequest"];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dictionnary
                                                       options:kNilOptions
                                                         error:&error];

    NSString *urlString =@"http://...................php";

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    [request setHTTPBody:jsonData];
    NSURLResponse *response = NULL;
    NSError *requestError = NULL;

    NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&requestError];

    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] ;
```

But i am not getting correct JSON, can you please check my code and let me know where is my mistake. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: unclear what you're asking.

Comment: @Virussmcahere is my one entity class with name "Store", only i need to convert this class object to JSON. but i dont know where i m getting mistake.

Comment: No actually it is not crashing anywhere, but it's not coming in JSON format and also value is not coming.

Comment: You should use `NSJSONSerialization`

Comment: My JSON is coming in one scope. but it should cum in more than one scope.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43042/discussion-between-viruss-mca-and-anand-gautam)

Comment: I am adding my rest code for posting on server. Please check my updated question.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43042/discussion-between-viruss-mca-and-anand-gautam)

Comment: You've now added the JSON serialization to your question and it looks like you should get a reasonable result. Can you tell us how the JSON data you're getting is incorrect?

Comment: @CalebFor asking in stackoverflow, i have written only two dummy classes, in actually my main entity have different different sub entiy clas and aftre printing JSON String in console, it is displaying : {"StoreRequest":[{"signOutStatus":false,"greetingStatus":false,"isBackFromVisit"‌​:false,"digitalMerchandisingStatus":false,"feedbackStatus":false,"storeRegion":"B‌​ishan Junction 8","isSubmit":false,"storeName":"Best Denki","storeId":"SG-2","planVisitStatus":false,"storeProfileId":5,"merchandisin‌​gStatus":false}]}

Comment: And please check my last question edited timing..i have used JSON serialization from before itself.

Comment: I don't see anything that's obviously wrong with that JSON -- can you be more specific?

Comment: I suspect that part of your confusion is that you've been looking at Java examples of JSON processing where they routinely "serialize" Java objects into JSON and "reconstitute" them.  This is a somewhat unnatural use of JSON -- it's much easier to comprehend if you just go from dictionaries and arrays to JSON "objects" and arrays (and back).  There are Objective-C toolkits to do it the Java way, but they aren't that popular.  So decide on a dictionary/array representation of your object, create the dictionaries/arrays, and "serialize" those into JSON.

Comment: I want JSON String like {
    "Checklist": [
        {
            "vm_code": "SGVM0001",
            "store_id": "SG-12",
            "store_name": "Best Denki",
            "store_address": "Ngee Ann City",
            "visit_date": {
                "date": "2013-12-04 00:00:00",
                "timezone_type": 3,
                "timezone": "Asia/Calcutta"
            }
            "sign_in": {
                "date": "2013-12-05 11:03:00",
                "timezone_type": 3,
                "timezone": "Asia/Calcutta"
            }]

Comment: Well, you're missing some closing `}` characters.

Comment: But if that's roughly what you want, you should, before serialization, have a dictionary with an element in it named "Checklist", and that element should be an NSArray with several dictionaries in it.  (Hard to tell how the dictionaries should be arranged due to the missing characters.)

Comment: @HotLicksThanks, that i have shown u one roughly JSON.

Comment: Look at the code in your `for` loop where you're adding values to `dictionnary`, and then compare that to what's in your JSON. If you want something different in your JSON, you'll need to change what you're adding to `dictionnary` to make that happen.

Comment: Your earlier JSON listing was not generated by the above code, so we're kind of feeling around in the dark here.

Comment: @CalebCan you tell me what things i need to change ? can u show me some sample for that..

Comment: @HotLicksYes u r totally correct. I have sent all key value pair for sample to know how i will generate proper JSON using 2 entity class(basic).

Comment: When you get your dictionary structure created, NSLog it.  NSLog will present the structure in a format that roughly matches JSON, only `()` is used instead of `[]`, `=` is used instead of `:`, and the use of quote marks is irregular.  But you can quickly see if the layout is correct.  Also, convert your JSON NSData object to an NSString and log that, so you can see the final JSON.

Comment: Can you pls show me some sample or refer any tutorial for this issue.

Answer (score 1):

> But i am not getting correct JSON, can you please check my code and let me know where is my mistake.

The problem is that you're not creating a JSON representation of the object anywhere; you're only creating a dictionary. Dictionaries can be converted to JSON (provided that they only contain certain types of data), but they're not JSON natively -- they're Objective-C objects. You probably want to add a call like:

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSData *json = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dictionnary options:0 error:&error];
```

You've shown us the NSCoding methods in your two classes, but you should understand that NSJSONSerialization doesn't rely on NSCoding, so none of that code is going to come into play.

**Update:** After modifying your example to include NSJSONSerialization, you say you're getting JSON that looks like this:

```
{"StoreRequest":[{"signOutStatus":false,"greetingStatus":false,"isBackFromVisit"‌​‌​:false,"digitalMerchandisingStatus":false,"feedbackStatus":false,"storeRegion":‌​"B‌​ishan Junction 8","isSubmit":false,"storeName":"Best Denki","storeId":"SG-2","planVisitStatus":false,"storeProfileId":5,"merchandisin‌​‌​gStatus":false}]}
```

That appears to be correct, given the values that you've added to `dictionnary`. But you say that what you *want* is:

```
{ "Checklist": [ { "vm_code": "SGVM0001", "store_id": "SG-12", "store_name": "Best Denki", "store_address": "Ngee Ann City", "visit_date": { "date": "2013-12-04 00:00:00", "timezone_type": 3, "timezone": "Asia/Calcutta" } "sign_in": { "date": "2013-12-05 11:03:00", "timezone_type": 3, "timezone": "Asia/Calcutta" }]
```

That doesn't at all match the object that you're passing to NSJSONSerialization. So, the problem here is that you're supplying incorrect data to NSJSONSerialization.

Comment: @CalebThanksActually NSCoding, i have taken to display value in their fields. I am using NSJSONSerialization but still its not showing.

Answer (score 1):

If you are working on iOS 5+, then you can use [NSJSONSerialization](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

```
NSData *data= [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:storeJSONArray 
                                                   options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted
                                                     error:nil];
if (data)
{
    NSString *json = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"JSON : %@",json );
}
```

Comment: @MidhunThanks..Yes, i am working on iOS 5+. please check my updated question. I am posting an object on server using php url.

Comment: @MidhunMPIt is displaying only one scope in JSON.

Comment: @AnandGautam: are you sure that your storeJSONArray contains all the objects ? I think it have only one object.

Comment: @MidhuniYes this storeJSONArray is an array of Store objects only. But store has one more entity class called "Sign In"

Comment: @AnandGautam: so what ? You added those value to a NSDictionary and added that to array. So the value in same level. Else convert your array1 and check

Answer (score 1):

You should serialize your NSMutableDictionary to JSON.
You can do this by using NSJSONSerialization:

```
NSError *error;
NSData *myData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:storeJSON options:0 error:&error];
NSString *myJSON = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[myData bytes]];
```

This should give you your JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
NSError *error; 
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dictionaryOrArrayToOutput 
                                                   options:kNilOptions // Pass 0 if you don't care about the readability of the generated string
                                                     error:&error];

if (! jsonData) {
    NSLog(@"Got an error: %@", error);
} else {
    NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}
```