# Want to create a json and send it to a url

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I have created a json using NSDictionary. Here is my code.

```
NSArray *propertyNames1 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Name", @"Lat", @"Lng", nil];

NSArray *propertyValues1 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"testName1", @"32.345453", @"23.5456346", nil];


NSDictionary *properties1 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:propertyValues1 forKeys:propertyNames1];
```

I want to send it to a url.For that i used this code.

```
NSString *urlString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http:example.com];
NSMutableURLRequest *mrequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[mrequest setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[mrequest setHTTPMethod:@"PUT"];
[mrequest setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

 NSString *post =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",properties1];
 NSData *body = [NSData dataWithBytes: [post1 UTF8String] length:[post1 length]];

[mrequest setHTTPBody:body];

NSURLConnection *connection=[[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:mrequest delegate:self];

if(connection)
{
    webdata = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
}
```

But it post into the url as

{
  "{\n    Lat ": " \"32.345453\";\n    Lng = \"23.5456346\";\n    Name = testName1;\n}"
}

I need the output as

```
{
  {
    "Lat": "32.345453"
    "Lng": "23.5456346"
    "Name": "testName1"
  }
}
```

please help me...

Comment: See http://www.codetuition.com/ios-tutorials/convert-nsdictionary-or-nsarray-to-json-nsstring-and-vice-versa/ . This should get you pointed in the right direction.

Comment: set `application/json` for Content-Type header,

Comment: Check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20543740/issue-convert-an-object-to-json-in-ios/20543998#20543998

Comment: you are sending raw NSData and not with NSJSONSerialization  serialized NSData, which is pretty easy to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

//build an info object and convert to json

```
    NSDictionary *properties1 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:propertyValues1 forKeys:propertyNames1];

    //convert object to data
    NSData* jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject: properties1 options:kNilOptions error:&error];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com"]];];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"PUT"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    [request setHTTPBody:jsonData];

    // print json:
    NSLog(@"JSON summary: %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData
                                                     encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    if(connection)
    {
      webdata = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
use the following 

jsonDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[jsonDictionary setObject:@value1" forKey:@"Lat"];
[jsonDictionary setObject:@"value2" forKey:@"Lng"];
[jsonDictionary setObject:@"value3"   forKey:@"Name"];


//Set the URL YOU WILL PROVIDE
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://....."];


NSData *jsonData=[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:jsonDictionary
                                                 options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted 
                                                   error:nil];


ASIFormDataRequest *request= [[ASIFormDataRequest alloc] initWithURL:url :@"POST"];
[request setData:jsonData forKey:nil];
[request setDelegate:self];
[request startAsynchronous];
```

Good luck:)

Answer (score 0):

To convert the dictionary into JSON, you should not use below line:

```
NSString *post =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",properties1];
```

Instead of that you should use below line:

```
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:properties1
                                                       options:0
                                                         error:&error];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use SBJSON https://github.com/dekkers/sbjson

```
import JSON.h

NSString *post =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[properties1 JSONRepresentation]];
```