# JSON from NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsmutabledictionary

I would like to create a JSON compatible dictionary for APNs messages, that looks like this:

```
{
      "aps" : {
        "alert": "new push"
      }
}
```

Actually i could create this:

```
  {
        aps = {
            alert = "new push";
        };
    }
```

This is my actual code:

```
    NSString *content = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"new push."];
    self.dict1 = @{ @"alert": content} ;

    NSMutableDictionary *newPush = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [newPush setObject:self.dict1 forKey:@"aps"];
```

Somebody could explain me, that what I'm doing wrong? How can I convert it to the proper format?

---

update

```
 NSDictionary *dict = @{ @"aps" : @{ @"alert" : content } };


//create the json
NSError *error;
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dict
                                                   options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted
                                                     error:&error];

NSString* jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

I've got this suggestion from the console: `There was an error sending the data to the origin. Be sure you didn't try to send non-object or non-JSON data.`

Comment: Nothing that should work, although it's a bit inefficient and it's not clear why you're using `self.dict1` (a property) rather than a local variable.

Comment: You can just do `NSDictionary *dict = @{ @"aps" : @{ "alert" : @"new push" } };` (pretty much the way you wrote it in the first two examples).

Comment: I agree with @trojanfoe, you're better off defining it literally.

Comment: @trojanfoe thank you, great tip.  Please add it as an answer and I can accept it.

Comment: So far as I can tell, you have the proper format.  Remember that an NSDictionary will not dump *exactly* like the equivalent JSON:  `=` is used instead of `:`, `;` is used between elements instead of `,` and simple character strings (without blanks or special characters) will not be surrounded by quotes.  When you convert to JSON with NSJSONSerialization, however, the resulting JSON will look just fine.

Comment: @HotLicks After I created the dictionary, I must convert it with NSJSONSerialization?

Comment: If you want real JSON, yes.  (Unfortuntely, NSJSONSerialization will only return an NSData, so to test your code and see the result you must use `NSString* jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:theJsonNSData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];`.)

Comment: (@anatoliy_v had a complete answer including all this, but for some reason he deleted it.)

Comment: @HotLicks I need NSDictionary, NSArray or NSString, therefore your jsonString version could be good, I will try it now.

Comment: "I need NSDictionary, NSArray or NSString" -- that doesn't make sense.  You should need either an NSData or an NSString as the "final" JSON.  NSDictionary/NSArray *is not* the same as JSON, it's just that you can, within limits, convert back and forth between.

Comment: @HotLicks I've updated my answer, it seems that I was wrong, and NSData will be a right format :).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Issue : Convert an Object to json in iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20543740/issue-convert-an-object-to-json-in-ios)

Comment: "I need NSDictionary etc." doesn't make sense at all - you had an NSDictionary to start with. If you wanted an NSDictionary, you'd just do _nothing_ and keep your NSDictionary. You _want_ NSData, which you can save in a file, send to a server etc.

Comment: @trojanfoe where is your answer? it works :)

Comment: I had deleted it as it wasn't complete. I've undeleted now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just do

```
NSDictionary *dict = @{
    @"aps" : @{ @"alert" : @"new push" }
};
```

(pretty much the way you wrote it in the first two code examples).

And then use `NSJSONSerialization` to create the formatted JSON.

Answer (score 1):

Use NSJSONSerialization to convert Dictionary or NSArray to an json object

```
...
NSError *error; 
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:newPush 
                                        options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted 
                                        error:&error];
...
```